# Primefaces, ajax call blocks the interface

Tags: ajax, jsf, primefaces

I have an JSF application with Primefaces 5.1 components and I have a problem regarding the Primefaces ajax calls.

On the view, there is a hidden `<p:commandButton>` that every `x` seconds it is triggered(by `event="click"`) and a web-service call is done. Now, the problem is that when this ajax call is executing, the whole UI it gets blocked and the user can't interact with the application anymore.This is a huge problem for me since this call can take up to 1 second.

For example, if the user types something in an input field, and in the same time the ajax call is done, everything the user typed is displayed after the call is completed.

My question is the following: Does anyone experienced the same problem? If yes do you find a way of doing things as the ajax call won't block the UI? Thank you.

I must add that the `commandButton` component have an `async` attribute. I have set the attribute to `true`, but the problem persists.

Comment: There is no synchronous rhythm while using AJAX. AJAX sends asynchronous requests that should not cause the whole UI to block. How does that happen?

Comment: Hello @Tiny, It seems that by setting the property global="false" on the component, the issue it's solved. The global="false" will not trigger the primefaces ajax status anymore for that explicit component (by primefaces ajax status I mean: pfAjaxSend,pfAjaxComplete, etc.) This behavior is making me think that the cause of this is somewhere in the code added by me on $(document).on("pfAjaxComplete", function(event, xhr, options)

Comment: That is why you should always post a fully working but minimalistic example of all relevant code